# Type 'Observable<true | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs, angular-observable

I am trying to create an authorized system for users.I am using Angular11.I am absolutely new in angular.I return also a boolean type in my code. but still, I found an error.

here is my code below:-

**auth.guard.ts

(here is the main problem)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AccountService } from '../_services/account.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private accountService : AccountService, private toastr : ToastrService){}
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
      map(user => {
        if(user) return true;
        this.toastr.error(error);
      })
    )
  }
  
}
```

**account.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../_models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {

  baseUrl='https://localhost:5001/api/';
  private currentUserSource =new ReplaySubject<User> (1);
  currentUser$=this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  

  constructor(private http :HttpClient) { }

  login(model:any)
  {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl+'account/login',model).pipe(

      map((response:User)=>{

        const user=response;
        if(user){
          localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }

  register(model:any)
  {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl +'account/register',model).pipe(
      map((user:User)=>{
        if(user){
          localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
        return user;
        
      })
    )
    
  }



  setCurrentUser(user:User)
  {
    this.currentUserSource.next(user);
  }





  logout()
  {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');  
    
    this.currentUserSource.next(null as any);
  }
}
```

**my error is:-**

[image]

why error I didn't understand. how I resolve this issue. please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error indicatest that the canActivate method is not returning an Observable< boolean > but an Obserable<true | undefined>

So lets inspect your map pipe to understand why this is the case:

```
map(user => {
        // we only return here so
        // only true is possible to be returned
        if(user) return true;
        // after this line nothing will be returned so the observable can only return true | undefinded
        this.toastr.error(error);
      })
```

You can fix this by ensuring to always return a bool value like this

```
map(user => {
        if(user) return true;
        this.toastr.error(error);
        // this line bellow is new it changes the return type from true | undefined into boolean
        return false;
      })
```

Comment: hey martin,I am surprised. because.looking like your code and my posted code are looking same.but when i copy paste your code it works,but my posted code not works. where actually you change . i am glad if you clarify that.

Comment: Sure, there is a minimal difference inside the map pipe. I,v mad an update to my answer with a comment inside the map sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the observable instead of only boolean value:

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
          map(user => {
            if(user) { 
               return of(true);
               }
            this.toastr.error(error);
          })
        )
      }
```

If you are using rxjs6 then modify the above as:

```
import { of as observableOf, Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
          map(user => {
            if(user) { 
               return observableOf(true);
               }
            this.toastr.error(error);
          })
        )
      }
```

Comment: I am using Angular11